# Is it possible to get this "chroma-shift" effect with OpenGL shaders

Tags: opengl, bitmap, shader

I'd like to be able to produce this effect, to be specific, the color-crawl / color-shift.

[image: color shift]

Is this possible with OpenGL shaders, or do I need to use another technique?

I'm new to OpenGL and I'd like try this as a getting started exercise, however if there's a better way of doing this, ultimately I want to produce this effect.

FYI I'm using Cinder as my OpenGL framework.

I know this isn't much information, but I'm having trouble even finding out what this effect is really called, so I can't google it.

Comment: FYI: The names you are looking for are 'color fringe', 'chromatic aberration' and 'color shifting'. All three refer to the same thing. It'll be hard to find info on how to produce this effect, but plenty on how to remove it.

Comment: Luckily I found this ... http://www.paulsprojects.net/opengl/refract/refract.html

Comment: @Miguel - I have seen it referred to as chroma-crawl or chroma-shift too, but that was a long time ago, 1983 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you with the name of the effect, but I have an idea to produce this effect. My understanding is that each color component is shifted by some amount. A simple translation to the right of left of individual color components produced the black and white original image:

[image: black and white image]

#### Steps to get the image you want

1. Get the source black and white image in a texture. If it's the result of other rendering, copy it to a texture.
2. Render a full screen quad (or the size you want) with texture coordinates from (0,0) to (1,1) and with the texture attached.
3. Apply a fragment shader that samples 3 times the input texture with a different shift in texture coordinates. e.g. -2 texels, 0 texel and +2 texel offsets. You can expirement and try more samples if you want and at different offsets.
4. Combine those 3 samples by keeping only 1 color component of each.

#### Alternate if performance doesn't matter or shaders are not available

Don't use a pixel shader but instead on OpenGL blending with the ADD function. Render 3 times that same full screen quad with the texture attached and use the texture matrix to offset the lookups each time. Mask the output colormask differently for each pass and you get the same result: pass 1 => red, pass 2 => green, pass 3 => blue.

Comment: It's called chromatic abberation, and it also works for colored images.

Answer (score 4):

The effect you're looking for is called *chromatic abberation*, you can it look up at Wikipedia. You were given a solution already, but I think it's my duty being a physicist, to give you a deeper understanding of what is going on, and how the effect can be generalized.

Remember that every camera has some aperture and light usually is described as waves. The interaction of waves with an aperture is called *diffraction*, but when it comes down mathematically it's just a *convolution* of the wave function with the fourier transform of the aperture function. Diffraction depends on the wavelength, so this creates a spatial shift depending on the color. The other effect contributing is dispersion, i.e. the dependence on refraction of the wavelength. Again diffraction can be described by a convolution.

Now convolutions can be chained up, yielding a total *convolution kernel*. In the case of Gauss blurring filter the convolution kernel is a Gauss distribution identical in all channels. But you can have different convolution kernels for each target channel. What @bernie suggestet are actually box convolution kernels, shifted by a few pixels in each channel.

This is a nice tutorial about convolution filtering with GLSL. You may use *for loops* as well instead of unrolling the loops.
http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/image_filtering_p2.php

I suggest you use some Gauss shaped kernels, with the blurring for red and blue being stronger than green, and of course slightly shifted center points.

Comment: I wish I could mark both of these replies as the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GeexLab have a demo of Chromatic Abberation, with source in their Shader Library [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20101008/shader-library-chromatic-aberration-demo-glsl/).